# JS analogue for Excel's regex

Tags: javascript, regex, excel

I've got an Excel document which uses regex. The expression is like this:

```
*<*>*
```

* is any array of symbols (including empty one).
There are some matching strings examples:

```
abc<>abc
<abc>
<>
```

Can you help me with function in JS, which will return true, if the passed string is correct for this regex, otherwise it has to return false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that set of any number of characters can be represented as `.*`, then the right way is:

```
/^.*<.*>.*$/.test(str);
```

**REF:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
var str = 'some<blah>thing';
patt=/.*<.*>.*/g;
result=patt.test(str);
document.write("<br>Returned value: " + result);
```

Test it here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_regexp_test